# how to fix this "hook-fu-mode" error in doom emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am getting this error in Doom Emacs startup.

> Error (doom-first-buffer-hook) : Error runing hook "hook-fu-mode" because: (file-missing Cannot open load file No such file or directorry undo-fu) Disable showing Disable logging

[screenshort](https://preview.redd.it/zjgwhz4f63pa1.png?width=1366&format=png&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=b9e7a2a777c44e45a39734edd6bade8f3efacfc7)

I just installed Emacs and then I also installed doom version.

Comment: The question is likely a duplicate, but I don't have time now to search for that...

Comment: There's no `hook-fu-mode` error shown in your screenshot. The question is poorly posed.

Answer (score 0):

(You really should copy code and error messages correctly, i.e., exactly. Screenshots don't substitute for correctly written questions.)

You need to put library `undo-fu` in your `load-path`.

Comment: Please elaborate where to find undo-fu  and does load-path mean environment variables settings in windows ? i am just getting started with emacs sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Seriously? **Your error message** says this: `Error running "undo-fu-mode" because: (file-missing Cannot open load file No such file or directory undo-fu)`. (Screenshots are not very accessible and are unsearchable.)

Comment: *Read your error message.* Use `C-h v load-path` to learn about `load-path`. Read the manual about it. Put library `undo-fu.el` in your `load-path`. If you don't have that library then google for it.

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments - if you have additional questions then post them as separate questions. Thx.